# ¿Cuál es la función del caracter '?' en esta linea de código?

Tags: javascript

Estoy analizando un código de una app en javascipt y no entiendo como funciona la asignación de un valor, que va así en esta linea: `object.setValue(valor == 7 ? 40 : 0);`. (también lo he visto en php y java)

A mi parecer, parece una estructura de `if` (si valor es igual a 7, setValue toma como argumento 40, sino el argumento es 0) ¿estoy en lo correcto?

¿Qué nombre tiene ese tipo de asignación o esa estrucura?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas en lo correcto, y ello se conoce como `shorthand conditionals` los operadores de `shorthand conditionals` a su vez se descomponen en **2 operadores** los cuales se llaman operadores ternarios, donde el simbolo **?** hace referencia a `if` y el simbolo `:` hace referencia a `else`.

En pocas palabras los `shorthand conditionals` son condicionales cortas que nos permiten evaluar una expresión de manera mas corta, ademas las condicionales cortas pueden tener a su vez condicionales cortas anidadas, creando expresiones que no tienen un simbolo directo para la expresión `else if` pero que hacen la función equivalente de un `else if`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const lon = 2.14;
const lan = 3.16;

const res = lon >= 2.14 ? lon == 2.14 ? lon : lan : lon;
console.log(res);
```

En esa expresión condicional seteamos un valor dependiendo de otros 2, mas especificamente usamos un `shorthand conditional` anidado para hacer dos comprobaciones, vamos a ver el proceso:

```
El valor de lon es mayor o igual a 2.14 ?
   El valor de lon es igual a 2.14 ?
     si las dos anteriores se cumplen devuelve lon
   de lo contrario devuelve lan
de lo contrario devuelve lon
```

Es asi como se evalua esa expresión condicional.

Analizando un poco tu expresión:

```
object.setValue(valor == 7 ? 40 : 0);
```

Podemos decir que equivale a comparar el `valor` de la variable `valor` con el numero `7` si es igual devuelve `40` como valor, si es un numero distinto de 7 devuelve `0`.

Haciendo que los posibles valores que tome esa expresión sean siempre `40` o `0`, **ningun otro**.

Los `shorthand conditionals` son muchas vecez utiles para acortar nuestro código.

Answer (score 5):

La expresión `cond ? exp1 : exp2` no es una asignación propiamente como tal. Corresponde al **operador ternario** y está presente en múltiples lenguajes.

Como produce un resultado, se puede utilizar como argumento para una función o asignación.

Puedes revisar su documentación para javascript en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator). Pero básicamente lo que describes es correcto.

Answer (score 3):

Eso se llama operacion ternaria, y eso es porque hay tres operandos ahi: A ? B : C
en este caso son ( A ,B ,C), A vendria ser una condicion siempre donde el resultado es ya sea false o true , ahora si A arroja true se ejecuta o en tu caso se asigna el valor 40 a tu funcion `object.setValue` de lo contrario si A arroja false se ejecuta o en tu caso se asigna el valor 0.
Entonces en resumen en tu caso es : si Valor es igual a 7 entonces pasar como parametro a la funcion el valor 40 , si no es igual a 7 pasar como parametro a la funcion el valor 0.
Entonces para mi la funcion del caracter ? es preguntar si lo que esta a su izquierda es true para ejecutar lo que esta a su derecha
`(5==5) ? console.log("true") : console.log("falso")`.

Answer (score 3):

Correcto, es una operación ternaria o condición if de una línea la sintaxis es simple:

```
expresion ? true : false;
```

en tu caso la **expresion** es => **(valor == 7)**

en caso de ser **true** es => **40**

caso contrario el **false** es => **0**